# How To Create A Sandbox Video Game

Tags: unity, architecture, world-design

I have a lot of experience with programming but I'm new in game development world, so I don't know what I don't know.

I want to create a MMORPG sandbox game. When I say sandbox game I have something in mind like Minecraft where you can make changes in the game world and they persist and all the players on the server can see them. Like if you plant a tree it will stay there even if you log out or if you dig the hole in the ground it will be there when you log out and other players would be able to see it.

For now I'm thinking about Unity as a game engine for this game. I also did some research and found some tutorials about RPG game creation. But I haven't found any information about how to create sandbox game. To be more precise about how to create editable world and how to save changes which were made to the initial game world.

Can you point me in the right direction? What should I search for? What would you suggest me to read so I would understand more about the things I'm getting in.

Answer (score 1):

Just save the changes as the user plays? Am I missing something here?

Either instantly (faster as you aren't saving the whole game at once, but the data adds up) or just regularly enough that you only lose a couple of minutes worth of data at a time (slower, as you have to save the entire game regularly, but uses less space)

Or best-case, combine both - save the server state every few minutes, but log the user actions n the meantime so you can "rebuild" the state. Each time you save, clear the log.